# `await` blocks node.js ability to receive and process websocket communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, websocket, async-await

I have a `node` script that spawns a random number of websocket connection.

In that same script, I `await` a call to my server to ping the websockets to count the number of responses within a timeout.

The problem is that the `await` blocks the websocket's ability to respond and they only DO respond after the `await` is resolved (after some timeout).

How can I spawn websockets, await a request and NOT block the websockets in the same script?

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { io } = require('socket.io-client');

const sock = async ({_id}) => {

  let socket = await io("ws://localhost:54321")

  socket.on('connect',(args) => {
    console.log(`${_id} connected to ws.`);
  })

  socket.on('ping',args => {
    console.log("PING RECEIVED ("+_id+")")
    socket.emit('pong',{socketId:_id,...args})
  })

  return socket;
}



(async function go(){

  let g_sockets = [];
  await Promise.all(['so0','s01'].map(async _id => {
    let s = await sock({_id})
    g_sockets.push(s);
  }))

  await new Promise((res,rej) => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:54321/roomSize').then(r => {
      console.log(r.data);
      res(r.data)
    })
  })
})()
```

Here, the `socket.on('ping',function)` only fires **AFTER** the `/roomSize` HTTP request resolves, which means the `/roomSize` calculation is incorrect.

My Flask server route looks like:

```
ping_holder = {}

@app.route('/roomSize')
def getRoomSize():

    pingId = str(random.randint(0,1e6))
    ping_holder[ pingId ] = []
    data = { "pingId":pingId }
    socketio.emit('ping',data=data,broadcast=True)

    time.sleep(1)


    return jsonify(ping_holder[pingId])
```

Comment: Using `then` instead of await might solve your issue

Comment: I can't use `then` because I can't allow the following lines to execute until that request is complete, I can only allow websockets and workers to function. 

Should/can I spawn these websockets in a worker_thread?